# How can I use the OneDrive SDK in a UWA on IoT Core

Tags: win-universal-app, iot, onedrive, windows-10-iot-core

I created a Windows 10 Universal App which accesses files and folders from OneDrive for a slideshow. Authentication and download works perfectly on Windows 10 PCs and Tablets that are signed in with a Microsoft Account.

When I run the application on Windows 10 IoT core, I get the error "The specified account does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070525)".

How can I log in with my Microsoft Account? Can I create a local account from a Microsoft Account on IoT Core? Or do I need to get a token from somewhere else and pass it to the device?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to show the login screen to the user and retrieve an access code, which will be used to login. Ensure your IoT device has internet access.

ms-iot team has made the Onedrive connector available on Github. More details here: https://github.com/ms-iot/onedrive-connector